# Is it possible to compile Python code for high efficiency?

Tags: python, performance, compilation

I'm trying to write some code that has to be as efficient as possible since I'll be doing thousands if not millions of operations in as short a time as possible.

Now I've got some code that does this written in C, but after some research on wrappers it seems above my skill level to delve in to that (especially since I have near no knowledge of C). Because of that, I was considering the possibility of re-writing the code/algorithm in python.

I've read that the reason most high efficiency tasks get done in C is because of the high efficiency of compiled languages and was wondering whether it is possible to compile python code to get close to the same efficiency using pure python.

The code would include specific bit manipulation, table lookups, bitwise logic and binary search or possibly using perfect hash.

Recap: I'm trying to code something that has to be efficient and was wondering whether it's possible to make python run at or near C efficiency. If so: how?

Comment: If it was possible to make Python run at or near C efficiency, why would anyone ever use C? You could try Cython, which is sort of a compromise solution.

Comment: you can try to use cython

Comment: numba or wrapping a c program

Comment: PyPy is a JITted Python that’s fast enough for many cases, supporting Python 3.5: https://pypy.org/

Comment: @Ryan maybe, especially since the function is going to be called many times, which is where PyPy really begins to shine after warming up, but given the use-case, it sounds more like a job for Cython. My general impression is that the attempts to make Python fast using JIT have only met with moderate success because, fundamentally, Python is too dynamic of a language. Cython adds static-typing, which is what let's an optimizing compiler *really* squeeze performance out of your code.

Comment: Also note, Cython was created to make writing C-extensions easy. You maybe be able to trivially compile your code using your C function that you've already written. Note, the [first bullet-point on the website](http://cython.org/) is "write Python code that calls back and forth from and to C or C++ code natively at any point."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Cython isn’t really easier to use than C, though, which seems to be the point of this question.

Comment: What’s the actual use-case? What is the operation it needs to do, how long does it take the C to do it, how long is acceptable?

Comment: @Ryan well, I certainly think it is easier to write an extension using Cython than writing one in pure C. But yeah, I agree. They question asks for "C-like" performance, but they don't want to use C. A JIT compiler may be an option, but they are in the realm of bit-manipulation, so I suspect that while the JITed solution will be a lot faster than vanilla Cpython, but may not be quite there. I've seen `numba` give great performance, better than Cython, but you have to use `numpy`.

Comment: @Ryan The actual usecase is calculating the odds of winning a poker hand either 1v1 or vs a group of people with unknown or known cards. This post is specifically about 1v1 with known cards. The program assigns a rank to all possible hands (including the one the player has) and outputs a value. In the 1v1 situation any case with 5 cards or less (opponents cards known) should take no more than 100 ms. The C code with perfect hash takes about 70ms. For 7 cards (have to find the best set of 5 out of 7) I'm willing to accept 500ms at the very maximum.

Comment: You should probably write the Python, check what kind of performance it has, then come back here for tips on improving it. Better than 500ms seems very achievable for that.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, Python is an interpreted language. The Python binaries compiled for your target machine not only execute your Python code, but also the interpreter that takes your code and interprets each command at run-time. That additional overhead of interpretation is what affects performance.

Languages that get compiled to native machine code and skip both interpretation (Python) and a Virtual Machine (JVM, .Net CLR) for the target CPU offer the best performance. Those are C and C++11/14/17.

You can use languages that get best performance that do use a particular kind of virtual machine, such as LLVM, which is useful for SSA. Clang (C/C++) and Rust can be compiled for LLVM (front-end), analyzed and optimized using LLVM-specific tools, and finally the Assembly and Linking using an LLVM back-end for the target machine. Either way, (direct or indirect machine code generation), native compilation offers the best performance.